# Why var cannot be the output of methods in C#?

Tags: c#

The compiler complains that it cannot resolve symbol `var`, but shouldn't it be able to infer the type of the object in the return statement and subsitute the implicit type `var` with the returning type?

Looking in MSDN, I was unable to find anything useful about this.

```
static var Method()
{
    .... // rest of the code
    return 10;
}
```

In the code, no matter if the method is static or local, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You can use dynamic though.

Comment: `var` is a contextual keyword, this is the wrong context.

Comment: what if your method never returns and/or throws an exception? what's the return type then? it *must have one* for the compiler to properly type-check its usage.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this. when calling a function, you need to know what its return type is. Imagine implementing an interface with a method whose return type is defined as "var". How would you implement that?

Comment: @Crwydryn It's theoretically possible.  Just like with the local variable it would be inferred at compile time.  It would look at the `return` expression(s), determine the common compile time type, and then to any code external to the method it would appear as if that type was specified explicitly.  It's that "determine the common compile time type" step that could be a problem though if there are multiple `return` statements, or other ambiguities such as is described in the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @Servy that's a fair point. I understand the benefits of var in local variables, I just don't think it necessarily fits at method level. Especially in abstract and interface definitions, but perhaps that's deviating from the original context of the question. Also, in a particularly long methods (which I appreciate is bad practice), it would become increasingly complicated for the compiler to infer the type, potentially slowing the environment down significantly